# Apply-Template only for nodes with ID based on parent subnode list

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm fairly new to XSLT and trying to solve a problem with a complex XML.
Here is an example on the XML and the output wanted.

Problem is that I need to select `Identity` based on the `Order`'s `IdentityOrder`. The compare should be done on `IdentityId`.

The Order should not be included in the list if the Identity's `LastName` is Empty

As you can see from my experiment, I can make this work with the transformation, but I'm not able to figure out how to exclude the orders where Identity's LastName is empty.

Appreciate all help I can get ;)

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>OR1</OrderNo>
        <BookingHeader>
            <BookingHeaderID>1</BookingHeaderID>
            <Identities>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>1</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>2</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Petter</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Smart</LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>3</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Betty</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Blue</LastName>
                </Identity>
            </Identities>
        </BookingHeader>
        <IdentityOrders>
            <IdentityOrder>
                <IdentityId>1</IdentityId>
                <Name>John Doe</Name>
            </IdentityOrder>
        </IdentityOrders>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>OR2</OrderNo>
        <BookingHeader>
            <BookingHeaderID>1</BookingHeaderID>
            <Identities>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>1</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>2</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Petter</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Smart</LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>3</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Betty</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Blue</LastName>
                </Identity>
            </Identities>
        </BookingHeader>
        <IdentityOrders>
            <IdentityOrder>
                <IdentityId>1</IdentityId>
                <Name>John Doe</Name>
            </IdentityOrder>
            <IdentityOrder>
                <IdentityId>3</IdentityId>
                <Name>Betty Blue</Name>
            </IdentityOrder>
        </IdentityOrders>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>OR3</OrderNo>
        <BookingHeader>
            <BookingHeaderID>1</BookingHeaderID>
            <Identities>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>1</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>2</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Petter</FirstName>
                    <LastName></LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>3</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Betty</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Blue</LastName>
                </Identity>
            </Identities>
        </BookingHeader>
        <IdentityOrders>
            <IdentityOrder>
                <IdentityId>2</IdentityId>
                <Name>Petter</Name>
            </IdentityOrder>
            <IdentityOrder>
                <IdentityId>3</IdentityId>
                <Name>Betty Blue</Name>
            </IdentityOrder>
        </IdentityOrders>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>OR4</OrderNo>
        <BookingHeader>
            <BookingHeaderID>2</BookingHeaderID>
            <Identities>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>4</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Roger</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Moore</LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>5</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Sylvester</FirstName>
                    <LastName></LastName>
                </Identity>
                <Identity>
                    <IdentityId>6</IdentityId>
                    <FirstName>Arnold</FirstName>
                    <LastName></LastName>
                </Identity>
            </Identities>
        </BookingHeader>
        <IdentityOrders>
            <IdentityOrder>
                <IdentityId>4</IdentityId>
                <Name>Roger Moore</Name>
            </IdentityOrder>
            <IdentityOrder>
                <IdentityId>5</IdentityId>
                <Name>Sylvester</Name>
            </IdentityOrder>
        </IdentityOrders>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

Wanted result after transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OrderNo>OR1</OrderNo>
    <Identities>
      <Identity>
        <IdentityId>1</IdentityId>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      </Identity>
    </Identities>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderNo>OR2</OrderNo>
    <Identities>
      <Identity>
        <IdentityId>1</IdentityId>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      </Identity>
      <Identity>
        <IdentityId>3</IdentityId>
        <FirstName>Betty</FirstName>
        <LastName>Blue</LastName>
      </Identity>
    </Identities>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderNo>OR3</OrderNo>
    <Identities>
      <Identity>
        <IdentityId>3</IdentityId>
        <FirstName>Betty</FirstName>
        <LastName>Blue</LastName>
      </Identity>
    </Identities>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderNo>OR4</OrderNo>
    <Identities>
      <Identity>
        <IdentityId>4</IdentityId>
        <FirstName>Roger</FirstName>
        <LastName>Moore</LastName>
      </Identity>
    </Identities>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

XSLT Transformation script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Orders>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Order[BookingHeader/Identities/Identity[LastName[text()]]]" />
        </Orders>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Order">tra
        <Order>
            <OrderNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderNo" />
            </OrderNo>
            <Identities>
                <xsl:for-each select="IdentityOrders/IdentityOrder">
                    <xsl:variable name="id" select="IdentityId" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="../../BookingHeader/Identities/Identity">
                        <xsl:if test="(IdentityId=$id) and (LastName!='') ">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Identities>
        </Order>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Identity">
        <Identity>
            <IdentityId>
                <xsl:value-of select="IdentityId" />
            </IdentityId>
            <FirstName>
                <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />
            </FirstName>
            <LastName>
                <xsl:value-of select="LastName" />
            </LastName>
        </Identity>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your example is very confusing because (a) there is no Identity with an empty LastNama, and (b) both orders have exactly the same Identities, which makes it difficult to see which one went where.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (!) you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="Identity" use="concat(IdentityId, '|', ancestor::Order/OrderNo)" />

<xsl:template match="/Orders">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Order">
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="key('id', concat(IdentityOrders/IdentityOrder/IdentityId, '|', OrderNo))" />
            <xsl:if test="$id/LastName/text()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="OrderNo"/>
                    <Identities>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$id"/>
                    </Identities>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)** to select the `Identity` whose `IdentityId` is listed in `IdentityOrders`. Then it checks if the selected `Identity` has a value in its `LastName` and if it does, it copies the `Order` along with its `OrderNo` and the selected `Identity`.

Note that the structure of your XML allows an `Order` to have more that one `IdentityOrder` - and it's not clear what the result should be in such case.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Sorry for the somewhat confusing example. Yes, there will be more than one identityorder in identityorders. This approach do not work when i add more than one idenityorder into the xml. Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: No, because as I said, it is not clear what the result should be in such case. Please edit your question and clarify the logic that needs to applied here.

Comment: So I updated my initial examples. Added a few more orders and a few more identities.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you want to accomplish here. You are giving examples, instead of explaining the rules. The only rule I see is *"The Order should not be included in the list if the Identity's LastName is Empty"* - and clearly your output does not follow this rule, because ALL Orders are included in the output.